# Binding error when binding to Width Property of MainView Window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a MainView Window whose width and height I'm trying to bind from its Code-Behind class.

```
<Window x:Class="RpP25.MainView"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:shared="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/shared"     
   xmlns:docking="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/docking"
   xmlns:themes="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/themes"
   xmlns:RpWin="clr-namespace:RpP25"
   xmlns:RpWinCmds="clr-namespace:RpP25.Commands"
   xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
   Title="{Binding Path=FileName, Converter={StaticResource WindowTitleNameConverter}}"
   Height="{Binding Path=WindowHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
   Width="{Binding Path=WindowWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
   Icon="images/CobWhite.ico"
   Loaded="Window_Loaded"
   Closing="Window_Closing">
```

The Code behind has the properties and also sets the datacontext to by ViewModel MainVM.

```
public partial class MainView : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Constant Fields
    private const double windowDefaultWidth_ = 720;
    private const double windowDefaultHeight_ = 400;

    // Private Fields
    private RegistryKey RegKey_;                                // Registry Key to hold Registry Subkey
    private WindowState windowState_ = WindowState.Normal;   // Display State of the MainWindow (Min,Max or Normal)
    private double windowWidth_ = windowDefaultWidth_;    // Width of the MainWindow
    private double windowHeight_ = windowDefaultHeight_;  // Height of the MainWindow

    #region Constructors

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainVM();

        // Get the state of the window and the width/height from the registry
        ReadRegistryValues();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Width of the Window
    /// </summary>
    public double WindowWidth
    {
        get { return windowWidth_; }
        set { windowWidth_ = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("WindowWidth"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Height of the Window
    /// </summary>
    public double WindowHeight
    {
        get { return windowHeight_; }
        set { windowHeight_ = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("windowHeight"); }
    }

    ...
}
```

This window is created from `App::OnStartup()`.

When I run the code the debugger throws the following error in the output window.

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=WindowHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'MainView' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

and a similar one for `WindowWidth`.

I thought I understood the binding modes, but I guess I was wrong :(

I was thinking that using FindAncestor looking for a Window would cause it to look up the visual tree until it found the MainView window that had my properties on it.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Width="{Binding Path=WindowWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Codebehind is the same element that your window. So use Self binding.